# Wrong syntax near keyword "OF" (filling table with identity column)

Tags: sql-server-2008, fill

I have made three tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE country_ (
    id_country  int NOT NULL IDENTITY(219,1),
    oid int NOT NULL,
    country_name_ru varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    country_name_en varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY  (id_country) 
  ) 


    CREATE TABLE region_ (
    id_region int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1612,1),
    id_country int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES country_(id_country),
    oid int  NOT NULL,
    region_name_ru varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    region_name_en varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id_region) 
 ) 

    CREATE TABLE city_ (
    id_city int NOT NULL  IDENTITY(17590,1),
    id_region int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES region_(id_region),
    id_country int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES country_(id_country),
    oid int NOT NULL,
    city_name_ru varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    city_name_en varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id_city) 
 )
```

Then I tried to fill them:

```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT country_  ON

    INSERT INTO country_  ( id_country,oid,country_name_ru,country_name_en) VALUES       (1,   3159, 'Россия', 'Russia');

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT country_  OF
```

In such way I filled region_  and  city_ tables, but  I have three errors:

> **wrong syntax near keyword "OF"**.

Any ideas?

Comment: I thik you missed an F... it is OFF (with double FF, starting with an O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its off

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT country_  OFF
```

you can read about this statement [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

as you can see, the syntax includes `OFF`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database. [ owner. ] ] { table } { ON | OFF }
```